# C# How to print a web page, without using javascript window.print() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I want to print the web page in asp.net application without using javascript function window.print().

Can anyone tell me  a short c# code to achieve my goal?

I do not want to print a document either, my requirement is to print what ever I have on the webpage. The print should be similar to what javascript Window.print() does.

Comment: The only way that I know to print without using the system dialog is through Google Cloud Print, which is a lot more involved than just firing something like window.print() and requires specific compatible hardware or a setup of a GCP client. You haven't provided any requirements for the how it should print, but you may be able to export to PDF instead of printing, depending on the needs. If you have more specific requirements you may get a better, more thorough answer.

Comment: thnx @Chris :My requirement is simple, whatever my web page has needed to be printed, keeping all the alignment and data as it is.

Comment: C# code is executed on the _server_, not the _client_, so that's not an option.  What;s your aversion to `Window.Print()`?

Comment: What did your research show up? What part of _"you can't print from a web browser without user interaction"_ didn't you understand? Or do you want to print on a printer attached to the web server?

Comment: @Stanley, Problem with window.print is because we are not able to force the printer to print in landscape layout. And our current dot net framework is 2.0 and it does not support css3 so we are not able to use css to change the orientation of page while we print. So I thought that we can use the c# print properties to make the printer layout : Landscape by default

Comment: Keep it simple, don't be harsh on something meant for it. Even if you are able to do it with C#, it will be code intesvie. Use Window.print().

Comment: Use <style type="text/css" media="print">
  @page { size: landscape; }
</style> if you like. This will allow you to print in landscape.

Comment: @Sikandar: I have tired this solution but its not working as I am using css2.1 and this is not supported in IE for CSS2.1

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question, it sounds like you want to print a web page (HTML) using C# code.

I've used wkhtmltopdf before (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) and on the same site, there's wkhtmltoimage. The utility runs as a command line tool, so it's easy to use in C#. After you have the image or PDF file (I'd opt for the image version), it should be easy to print out.

Your biggest concern is rendering the HTML into a page, that is what wkhtmltopdf/image does for you.

Comment: thnx @jacob, but we can not use third party tool as we need to get approvals and we have licencing issues with such third party software/tools.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a lot there. Printing is something the client (the web browser) has to do. The window.print() function tells the browser to print the page, and if you can't use javascript, then you have to '' the page on the server. If you want to print the page on the server side, then you have to take the HTML and convert it to some printable format like PDFs or rendered pictures.

Try out [selenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). You can get a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (running on the server) to 'screen capture' the page to a PNG. Then you can send that to the browser. Unfortunately, selenium web driver does not support PDF 'screenshots'.

There's also a nuget package for selenium if you're into that sort of thing.

Comment: thnx for your input, the problem is I work for a financial firm and we are kinda reluctant to use third party software. Its just client has that requirements so I can not help :(. Had to do this way.

Comment: @Sidharh You're asking someone else on SO to basically write complicated functionality for you, is this really so different?

Comment: @Kritner : The problem is I am working on old framework, I have tried all the things and somehow I am not able to change the orientation. I tried moving the page to 90 degrees before print and changed back to normal after print but somehow css is getting messed up.

Comment: If you need specific styles for print media, use the @media print query